# AttributeError: module 'caffe' has no attribute 'Net'

Tags: google-colaboratory, caffe, pycaffe

I tried to install Caffe on **Google Colab** according to this [Link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Huxwell/caffe-colab/blob/main/caffe_details.ipynb#scrollTo=Hw_lDn_BA7Bv). But, when I wanted to load the Caffe net and weights, I faced with this error.

```
# Load the Caffe net and weights.
net = caffe.Net(prototxt_filename, 1, weights=caffemodel_filename)
```

> AttributeError: module 'caffe' has no attribute 'Net'

Anyone, have an idea why this happen ? Thanks

Comment: I got the same problem; if you solve it. Can you share the solution? I will appreciate your help