# why do I get "AttributeError: module 'caffe' has no attribute 'Classifier'" when running Caffe?

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

My question is very close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236263/attributeerror-module-caffe-has-no-attribute-net).

I installed Caffe on google Colab, and I am trying to run [this open source CNN model.](http://opensurfaces.cs.cornell.edu/publications/minc/) the pre-trained models and the test can be [downloaded here](http://opensurfaces.cs.cornell.edu/static/minc/minc-model.tar.gz).

I followed these steps:

1. I repeated all the instructions in [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Huxwell/caffe-colab/blob/main/caffe_details.ipynb) to install Caffe on my google Colab.
2. I then downloaded the pre-trained models including the test.py [from this link (also mentioned above)](http://opensurfaces.cs.cornell.edu/static/minc/minc-model.tar.gz), using the following lines of code:

   !wget http://opensurfaces.cs.cornell.edu/static/minc/minc-model.tar.gz
3. I run the run the test.py, which includes this line of code:

   net=caffe.Classifier('deploy-{}.prototxt'.format(arch),'minc-{}.caffemodel'.format(arch),channel_swap=(2,1,0),mean=numpy.array([104,117,124]))

but I get the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'caffe' has no attribute 'Classifier'

[the code and the the Caffe folder on colab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXLJi.png)

I see "classifier.py"in caffe folder on google drive, are they the same thing? and if yes, how can I implement the address into the above mentioned line of code?

Thanks in advance.

this is the code I run before test.py to install caffe on colab.

```
!ls
!git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
!git reset --hard 9b891540183ddc834a02b2bd81b31afae71b2153 #reset to the newest revision that worked OK on 27.03.2021
# !sudo apt-cache search libhdf5-
# !sudo apt-cache search gflags
# !sudo apt --fix-broken install
!sudo apt-get install libgflags2.2 
!sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev
!sudo apt-get install libgoogle-glog-dev
# !sudo apt-get install libhdf5-10 - replaced with 100
!sudo apt-get install libhdf5-100
!sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
!sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
# !sudo apt-get install libhdf5-cpp-11 - replaced with 100
!sudo apt-get install libhdf5-cpp-100
!sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
!find /usr -iname "*hdf5.so"
# got: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
!find /usr -iname "*hdf5_hl.so"
!ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial.so     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so
!ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so
#!find /usr -iname "*hdf5.h*" # got:
# /usr/include/hdf5/serial/hdf5.h 
# /usr/include/opencv2/flann/hdf5.h
# Let's try the first one.
%env CPATH="/usr/include/hdf5/serial/"
#fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
!sudo apt-get install libleveldb-dev
!sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev
!sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev
!echo $CPATH
%cd caffe
!ls
!make clean
!cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
!sed -i 's/-gencode arch=compute_20/#-gencode arch=compute_20/'     Makefile.config #old cuda versions won't compile 
!sed -i 's/\/usr\/local\/include/\/usr\/local\/include     \/usr\/include\/hdf5\/serial\//'  Makefile.config #one of the 4     things needed to fix hdf5 issues
!sed -i 's/# OPENCV_VERSION := 3/OPENCV_VERSION := 3/'     Makefile.config #We actually use opencv 4.1.2, but it's similar enough to opencv 3.
!sed -i 's/code=compute_61/code=compute_61 -    gencode=arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -        gencode=arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=compute_75/' Makefile.config #support for new GPUs
!make all -j 4 # -j would use all availiable cores, but RAM related errors occur
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
import caffe
# !./data/mnist/get_mnist.sh #Yann Lecun's hosting sometimes fails with 503 error
# So we use alternative source of mnist dataset
!wget www.di.ens.fr/~lelarge/MNIST.tar.gz
!tar -zxvf MNIST.tar.gz
!cp -rv MNIST/raw/* data/mnist/

!./examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh
```

This is the `test.py` that I run(at first I get errors to "Place images to be classified in images/brick/*.jpg,     images/carpet/*.jpg, ...'", I create a folder named '`images`' and I put the `example.jpg` inside, then it gets solved.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from __future__ import division
from __future__ import with_statement
from __future__ import print_function

import caffe
import numpy
import glob
import os.path
import sys

if __name__=='__main__':
  if not os.path.exists('images'):
    print('Place images to be classified in images/brick/*.jpg,     images/carpet/*.jpg, ...')
sys.exit(1)
  categories=[x.strip() for x in open('categories.txt').readlines()]

  arch='googlenet' # googlenet, vgg16 or alexnet
  net=caffe.Classifier('deploy-{}.prototxt'.format(arch),'minc-{}.caffemodel'.format(arch),channel_swap=(2,1,0),mean=numpy.array([104,117,124]))

  result={}
  for i,x in enumerate(categories):
    result[x]=[]
    for j,y in     enumerate(sorted(glob.glob('images/{}/*'.format(x)))):
      z=net.predict([caffe.io.load_image(y)*255.0])[0]
  k=z.argmax()
  print(arch,y,categories[k],z[k],k==i)
  result[x].append(k==i)
    for i,x in enumerate(categories):
      print(arch,x,sum(result[x])/len(result[x]))
    print(arch,sum(sum(x) for x in result.values())/sum(len(x) for x in result.values()))
```

and I receive this error :

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 18
> 19   arch='googlenet' # googlenet, vgg16 or alexnet
> ---> 20   net=caffe.Classifier('deploy-{}.prototxt'.format(arch),'minc-{}.caffemodel'.format(arch),channel_swap=(2,1,0),mean=numpy.array([104,117,124]))
> 21
> 22   result={}
>
> AttributeError: module 'caffe' has no attribute 'Classifier'

Comment: why *should* caffe have a Classifier? where is that promised/documented? what caffe did you install? is it the real caffe? did the import succeed? do you have **any** file called `caffe.py`? show all your code, all the steps. review [mre] and [ask]. a screenshot of text is not okay.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I added other details about my problem and revised the text based on the two instruction pages. I don't have any file called caffe.py. but I assume this is the real caffe, this is the link I download it from: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git

Comment: also the classifier could be found here :https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/9b891540183ddc834a02b2bd81b31afae71b2153/python/caffe/classifier.py

Comment: the only other instances of this type of issue I've seen involve other packages trying to provide the same namespace... so perhaps another package tries to provide the `caffe` namespace. you need to investigate what packages you have installed, via pip or via the operating system's packages. it certainly doesn't help that you build caffe yourself.